# What's the difference between a/an and the?

Tags: difference, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

For example:

"I sent a report about a wrong item."

VS.

"I sent a report about the wrong item."

I'm confused. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I sent a report about a wrong item." is saying that you sent a report about no specific item. "I sent a report about the wrong item." is saying that there is a specific incorrect item that you wrote a report about. Another example is "I want a cat." which means that there is no certain cat you want, just a cat in general. "I want the cat." means that there is a certain cat you want

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in the emphasis.

When you say "I sent a report about a wrong item" you are emphasizing the *verb* (sending) rather than the *indirect object* (a generic wrong item). Perhaps you are being asked to account for your activities for the day, or you are writing out a list of job responsibilities to demonstrate what a replacement worker would have to do in your place.

When you say "I sent a report about the wrong item" you are emphasizing the *indirect object* (this specific wrong item). Perhaps the wrong item is being discussed, and you are asked what you have done to correct it. You are still emphasizing the *verb* (sending) and there is a little bit more emphasis on the *direct object* (a report) as well.